# How do I add custom fields to the "Edit page" admin screen?

Tags: plugins, custom-field, pages, wp-admin

I'm writing a plugin to add a set of custom fields to the "edit page" admin screen, using [Custom Meta Boxes 2 plugin](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2).
That's what I wrote so far:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name:     foo Page Banner
 * Plugin URI:      http://www.foo.eu
 * Description:     foo custom widget to display a media element banner with custom text, title and links
 * Text Domain:     foo
 * Domain Path:     /languages
 * Version:         0.0.1
 *
 * @package         foo_Page_Banner
 * @version         0.0.1
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

add_action( 'cmb2_init', 'add_foo_page_cmb2_metaboxes' );
function add_foo_page_cmb2_metaboxes() {

    $prefix = '_foo_page_';

    $cmb = new_cmb2_box( array(
        'id'           => $prefix . 'banner_media',
        'title'        => __( 'Banner media', 'foo' ),
        'object_types' => array( 'page' ),
        'context'      => 'advanced',
        'priority'     => 'default',
    ) );

    $cmb->add_field( array(
        'name' => __( 'Banner Title', 'foo' ),
        'id' => $prefix . 'banner_title',
        'type' => 'text_small',
        'default' => 'page title',
        'desc' => __( 'Banner Title', 'foo' ),
    ) );

    $cmb->add_field( array(
        'name' => __( 'Banner media', 'foo' ),
        'id' => $prefix . 'banner_media',
        'type' => 'file',
    ) );

    $cmb->add_field( array(
        'name' => __( 'Banner Description', 'foo' ),
        'id' => $prefix . 'banner_description',
        'type' => 'text_medium',
        'default' => 'page description',
    ) );

    $cmb->add_field( array(
        'name' => __( 'Banner Links', 'foo' ),
        'id' => $prefix . 'banner_links',
        'type' => 'text_url',
        'default' => 'http://www.example.com',
        'repeatable' => true,
    ) );

}
```

I sense I need to add specific action to load the `add_foo_page_cmb2_metaboxes` function only when the current admin screen is a page edit screen. Am I wrong? How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you code you are passsing 'Page' as object types.

Please update your code as follows:

```
$cmb = new_cmb2_box( array(
        'id'           => $prefix . 'banner_media',
        'title'        => __( 'Banner media', 'foo' ),
        'object_types' => array( 'post' , 'page' ),
        'context'      => 'advanced',
        'priority'     => 'default',
    ) );
```

When set object types to Post and Page both then it will be available to both post types. you can also include any custom post type as well.